# Error while running 'rake test' - Agile rails development book, Depot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': src/ruby-test/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:55: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
                                  image_url: fred.gif")
                                                      ^
src/ruby-test/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:57: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
        assert_equal "has already been taken", product...
                         ^
src/ruby-test/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:57: unterminated string meets end of file
src/ruby-test/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:57: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require': src/ruby-test/depot/test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
        description: 'Wibbles are fun'
                   ^
src/ruby-test/depot/test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
        image_url: 'lorem.jpg'
                  ^
src/ruby-test/depot/test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
        price: '19.95'
              ^
src/ruby-test/depot/test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
src/ruby-test/depot/test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:56: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
Errors running test:units! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p1...]>
Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p1...]>
```

Comment: The source that generates the error will likely help diagnoses.

Comment: @DaveNewton What did you edit? (I'm new here in SO..)

Comment: I put the errors in a code block so it was legible. You can see what was changed by clicking on the link "edited nn mins ago".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a double quote around a string, that `image_url: fred.gif"` should be `image_url: "fred.gif"`